# Power Shall Replace Object

Tags: powershell, replace

Can you please help me with the power shell way to replace "|" with "," to I can save this as CSV.

```
CF Hi|Cap Launch|Sales To
CF Hi|Cap Launch|Sales To|Systems
```

I have tried -replace(), however it add "," after every character.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CFInfoCenter Hierarchy|Capabilities Launchpad|Sales Tools
CFInfoCenter Hierarchy|Capabilities Launchpad|Sales Tools|Systems

Comment: The "|" character has a special meaning in regular expressions so you have to escape it in your replace. To escape a character we use a backslash, so try -replace "\|", ","

Comment: so was that the reason it was adding "," after each letter ?

Comment: Also, `-replace` is an operator, not a method so don't use `()` there

Comment: So, you are actually looking to add a new column `Systems` to the pipe-delimited CSV (that seems to not have headers)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'CF Hi|Cap Launch|Sales To
CF Hi|Cap Launch|Sales To|Systems'

$csv = $string.Replace('|',',')

New-Item -ItemType File test.csv
Add-Content .\test.csv $csv
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].